# Tortoise SVN: Network connection closed unexpectedly

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Note:  I see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644791/network-connection-closed-unexpectedly-upon-svn-checkout) but it does not help me.

I have installed `tortoise SVN` on `Windows 7` PC, my repository is on Linux server.  I created the both private and public keys using `PUTTYGEN` and saved the public key on `authorized_keys` file and added the private key using `PAGEANT`.
Previously I had all of this and the tortoise SVN worked correctly, but now I have some error when I want to checkout projects from server using the following command:

```
svn+ssh://user@x.x.x.x/...
```

Error:

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://user@x.x.x.x'
To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

Now in my /home/svnuser/.ssh I have two files:
`authorized_keys` and `db_rsa`.
I pasted the public key in the `authorized_keys` file, but don't know what should be copied in the `db_rsa`

Answer (score 0):

1. As suggested by error message: debug connectivity problems - connect to host in pure SSH-session, using PLink and PageAnt
2. **But** you'll discover already known problem: server-side Linux can't understand Putty's style key in authorized_keys and expect it in OpenSSH-compatible form (PuttyGen can perform such conversion)

Comment: Dear Lazy Badger, but what should I do?

Comment: I have read it, but I created my keys using PuttyGen. I can't understand your answer