# Location information has been specified incorrectly in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, svn, eclipse-plugin

I am new to the SVN(Subversion), After installation of these below plugins in eclipse, I got an error while importing project from repository.

[image]

Error while importing project from remote SVN repository

[image]

Comment: You have installed more than one connector. Which one do you use (Window > Preferences: Team > SVN: SVN Connector)? You use the `svn+ssh` protocol: Are you sure your *SSH Settings* are correct? If possible use another [protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2140954/6505250).

Comment: Any feedback on the answers you got?

Answer (score 1):

The screenshots suggests that you use an URL that starts with "svn+ssh" on a remote system. According to [this](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-basics-svn.html) that means you try to connect via *authenticated, encrypted TCP/IP access via custom protocol to a svnserve server*.

There are plenty of reasons why this could fail, so to get *closer* to a solution you have to increase the "verbosity" of svn output messages, as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644791/network-connection-closed-unexpectedly-upon-svn-checkout) for example. If that doesn't help - you can only dive deep into other similar problems, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606950/tortisesvn-svnssh-error-unable-to-connect-to-a-repository-at-url-network-c) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298237/svn-repository-stopped-working-with-svnssh-but-works-locally-on-the-server).

Comment: The question is about the Eclipse Subversive SVN client, not about the SVN command line client.

Comment: The first thing you want to ensure is: **connectivity**. And the **easiest** way to test that: remove all the additional complexity that using an eclipse plugin has - compared to simply running a command line tool. Beyond that: nobody prevents you from putting up a better answer. Rest assured: I would even upvote that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you run Eclipse on **Java 8** (today's SVN repositories usually use longer keys [than supported by older Java versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6852095/6505250))
2. You have installed two connectors (implementation of the SVN protocol), [JavaHL (native library/DLL + Java API) and SVNKit (100% Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7703748/6505250). Choose **SVNKit** (because it [is easier to install/configure](https://eclipse.org/subversive/installation-instructions.php#phase2)): *Window > Preferences: Team > SVN: SVN Connector*
3. Make sure your **SSH settings** (SSH Settings tab in the *New Repository Location* dialog) are correct or use [another protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2140973/6505250).

If this does not fix your problem, consider to update your 2+ years old [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/)/Subversive/SVNKit installation.

Comment: You should explain the differences between SVNKit and JavaHL.

Comment: I have added the explanations in brackets: connectors (implementation of the SVN protocol), JavaHL (native library/DLL + Java API) and SVNKit (100% Java)

Comment: Nice comprehensive list ... where: your first link is 6 years old; I very much doubt that he has such kind of problems.

Comment: @GhostCat Just follow the step-by-step instructions. Follow the links only if you are interested in the technical details. Step 1 solved the problems of two Subversive users who asked me in the last few months. Note, the key length problem will happen again with the upcoming Java 9 as soon as SVN servers will use longer keys than Java 8 supports. A personal remark: I want to help others and I do not see myself in competition with you.